# Update Multiple data

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, updates

I can't fix this:

```
$data=array(
for($i=1; $i<=$tot+1; $i++){    

array(                  

'id_jenisjadwal' => $this->input->post('jenis_jadwal'),

'bulan_tahunkp' => $bln_thn,

'id_ruang' => $this->input->post('ruang'.$i),

'tgl_sidangkp' => $this->input->post('tgl'.$i),

'jam_awalkp' => $this->input->post('awal'.$i),

'jam_akhirkp' => $this->input->post('akhir'.$i)

)
});
$this->db->update_batch('jadwal_kp',$data,'id_jenisjadwal');
```

Comment: What is your problem ?

Comment: Probably that this is not a valid php syntax for starters.

Comment: Interesting try though.

Comment: @AmalMurali, the first line starts an array literal and then its a for loop inside it. that's not valid.

Answer (score 1):

You are executing a loop where the definition for the array should exist.

```
$data=array();

  for($i=1; $i<=$tot+1; $i++){  

   $data[$i] = array(                  

 'id_jenisjadwal' => $this->input->post('jenis_jadwal'),

 'bulan_tahunkp' => $bln_thn,

'id_ruang' => $this->input->post('ruang'.$i),

 'tgl_sidangkp' => $this->input->post('tgl'.$i),

'jam_awalkp' => $this->input->post('awal'.$i),

'jam_akhirkp' => $this->input->post('akhir'.$i)

 );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wild stab in the dark ==

```
$data = array();

for($i=1; $i<=$tot+1; $i++){

$data[] = array(

your data bits in the middle .......

);

}
```